# Does this case break the rules of redux and its reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I read somewhere that in reducers I should never modify state, I should only add new data to it like so: `return [...state, action.payload];` or like so: `return [...state, ...action.payload];`

So in this `modify_favorites_reducer` is that case `CLEAR_FAVORITES` legit or it is against REDUX rules and philosophy?

```
import {
  ADD_TO_FAVORITES,
  INJECT_TO_FAVORITES,
  CLEAR_FAVORITES,
} from '../actions';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_FAVORITES:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case INJECT_TO_FAVORITES:
      return [...state, ...action.payload];
    case CLEAR_FAVORITES:
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

It does the job done and my code is working, but I don't know if it is ok to leave it like that.

Comment: `CLEAR_FAVORITES` is perfect reducer, create new array, how it should be.

Comment: That case doesn't modify the existing state, it determines (based on the action type) that the new state should be `[]`. Totally normal and valid in Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone from future reads this. `CLEAR_FAVORITES:` is perfectly fine, as some experienced users confirmed.

More info you can find in comments below my question.